# Calling REST endpoints in views?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using the Django REST framework package. I have several endpoints that I've already built to return data. I am calling these endpoints within Ajax to retrieve data. However, if a user does not have JavaScript enabled and presses let's say a subscribe button or a follow button for example, the action would be handled in the views.py file for that specific POST request. Would it be better to handle the request manually by doing a simple query in the views.py or is it better to just hand it off to the endpoint for that specific request inside the views.py?

I know I can use serialization in views.py, but which would be better using serialization or manually writing the queries to add the rows?

Comment: You could also call the serializer directly from views.py

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo Wouldn't that be repeating code though that's already in the API view? Also, wouldn't that also be less safe since in order to do POST requests we would have to mark the  view as csrf_exempt?

Comment: You wouldn't be repeating code, all the logic would be in the serializer, and you wouldn't need to make it csrf_exempt, it's a normal POST view, just that the logic is in the serializer

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo It says in the docs that it has to be csrf_exempt here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/ also do you think this would be better than just doing a query and adding a row?

Comment: "Note that because we want to be able to POST to this view from clients that won't have a CSRF token we need to mark the view as csrf_exempt", you can make the form have a csrf token, so that sentence won't apply

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo Hmm, I see. So do you think it would be better to call the serializer instead of just making a query?

Comment: By making a query do you mean something like `requests.post('/api/foo/bar')`? Yeah, I think using the serializer directly is the way to go

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo No, I mean using the ORM to create a row for the follow relationship for example something like: `p = Following(target=user.id, follower=follow.id)` and then `p.save()`

Comment: Oh, so duplicating the logic? Then yeah too, the serializer is the way to go too

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo Oh okay, so the serializer would be the way to go because we wont be duplicating the same logic?